# Show credit card error reason @ checkout

Tags: checkout, magento-2.1.2

I'm currently running 2.1.3 and utilizing Braintree processing at checkout. Currently, if a customer places an error with a bad credit card, wrong CVV number, or wrong address, they just get the error of

An error occurred on the server. Please try to place the order again.

What do I need to change in PaymentInformationManagement.php to override this and show the actual reason for decline? Such as card declined, cvv error, address error, etc.

Comment: The file you are looking for is PaymentDetailsHandler.php. Braintree returns different codes depending on the status of the payment: https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/general/processor-responses/authorization-responses you would need to check against those codes to determine why the payment failed

Answer (score 0):

Magento place order flow provides only high-level errors, it allows to make an application more secure. So it's not a good idea to show specific errors for a customer.

According to Magento Braintree implementation, it based on [Hosted Fields](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/hosted-fields/overview/javascript/v2), so all card data validation, like card number, expiration dates, CVV processes on the payment form.

Comment: So there's no way of showing the customer that the transaction isn't working because of card number, CVV, etc? Instead, they just see a generic message saying there was an error on the server, making them think it's the website, and not their card.

Comment: You can override default behavior but I don't recommend to do it. Also, I think it's a not particular case when a real card successfully validated on payment form but failed after authorization/sale transaction.